# chattr not working in SLES 10 SP2

Tags: linux, filesystems, sles

I have an ancient server with SLES 10 SP2, I want to change an attribute of file to immutable, I know that I need to do `chattr +i <file>`. But it does not seems to be working, the file attributes is not changed. And I'm out of my wits now. Where can I look to fix this problem?

[Here's a screenshot of my problem.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ybGSt.png)

P.S. e2fsprogs version is 1.38

Comment: What is the exact error message if any?

Comment: If you read the man page for your chattr does it allow `+i` ?

Comment: There is no error, it just that the file attribute not changed, and I believe the man page says it allowed +i. Of course, I ran that command as root.

Comment: and you're using `chattr` on a file system that supports it?

Comment: @AgusPurnomo What is the output of `lsattr <file>`?

Comment: yes, the filesystem is ext3, which I believe to support it. @ricmarques, please see the added screenshot.

Comment: @AgusPurnomo "chattr +i" is working for me on a SLES 10 SP2 machine with some "ext3" filesystems (for the root user). Could you edit your question to add the content of the "/etc/fstab" file? Have you tried to run the same command as root, without using sudo?